# AutoHotKey - DirCopy keeps throwing "failed" exception

Tags: exception, directory, copy, autohotkey, rights

I'm simply trying to copy a folder to another, but DirCopy keeps failing and I'm not sure why...

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

clipboard := A_Clipboard
arr := StrSplit(clipboard, "`n")
source_folder := "C:\Users\####\Documents\AutoHotkey\WT"
destination_folder := "C:\Users\###\Documents\AutoHotkey\PSDT"

Loop arr.length
{
    name_part := arr[A_Index]
    sps := StrSplit(name_part, A_Tab)

    name_part := sps[1]
    ep := sps[2]

    aim := ""
    dos := "FR " name_part " " ep

    Loop Files, source_folder "\FR " name_part "*", "D"
        aim := A_LoopFilePath 

    aim := Trim(aim "\" dos) 
        
    MsgBox ". " aim
    MsgBox "> " destination_folder "\" dos

    if DirExist(aim)
        MsgBox "The target folder does exist."
    DirCreate destination_folder "\Folder"

    DirCopy( aim, destination_folder "\" dos)

}
```

The `Folder` is created and the aim does exist.

I've tried to launch the script in admin mode (right-click : run as administrator)

Does anyone has an idea why this Exception is occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay! I've found the solution!

The problem came from the very source. The clipboard was filled from 4 cells in a sheet.

I thought the structure was

```
Elmt1 \t Elmt2 \n
Elmt3 \t Elmt4 \n
```

But it was not just a Line Feed, but a End Of Line instead.
So, the line to fix was at the beginning, corrected like this:

```
arr := StrSplit(clipboard, "`r`n")
```